# User Management In An Asp .NET Core App With Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm writing an app using ASP.NET Core (With the full .NET framework 4.6.1)  and I don't want to use EF core (Partly because of missing features, partly because I'm still accustomed to the edmx designer), so I'm sticking with EF 6 for now.

I've got them to play nice by keeping the EF 6 edmx in it's own project.

I'm now getting to the point where I want to introduce a user management system, so I've look at the built-in ASP.NET Core Identity.
I followed a tutorial, but when I try to "enable-migrations" on the model, I just get an unhelpful error message, which I'm assuming means "Sorry, no can-do unless you're fully on the ASP.Net Core framework, rather than still using the older full.Net framework option".

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."

I'd love to use ASP.NET Core Identity alongside my EF 6 dbContext if possible, so if anyone can make a suggestion there that would be great.

If that's not possible, I need a little guidance on what classes I should be using/implementing (Which will be compatible with both .NET core and EF6) to manage my users (Primarily in the AccountController, i.e. user registration, password resets, role management etc).

Or is the answer that I simply need to roll my own for this scenario and pretty much write everything starting from scratch?

Comment: Please don't say .NET Core when you mean ASP.NET Core since they're different thing and it will confuse the matter a lot.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Steviebob, did you ever come up with a good solution for this?  I'm having the exact same problem.